# Find words containing 20 vowels grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I found many similar questions but most of them ask for vowels in a row which is easy. I want to find words that contain 20 vowels not in a row using grep.

I originally thought grep -Ei [aeiou]{20} would do it but that seems to search only for 20 vowels in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression that searches for 20 vowels separated by any quantity of consonants.

```
grep -Ei "[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\ 
[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*"
```

The backslash is just informing the shell that the expression continues on the next line. It is not part of the regex itself.

If you understand that part, you can shorten it considerably using groups. This regexp is the same as above, but using groups in parenthesis with repetition.

```
grep -Ei "([aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*){20}"
```

Comment: Nice, I retract my initial statement ;)

Comment: What if there are 2 back to back vowels though? like "wood" for example if using that same grep with only {2}. Could I use the "?" so it only searches that 0-1 times?

Comment: @NickS `*` matches any number including zero, so it will also match back to back vowels

Comment: That will find 20 or more vowels on a line, not exactly 20 vowels in a word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's a problem that calls for just a regex. Here's a programmatic approach. We redefine the field separator to the empty string; each character is a field. We iterate over the line; if a character is a vowel we increment a counter. If, at the end of the string, the count is 20, we print it:

```
cat nicks.awk
BEGIN{
  FS=""
}
{
  c=0;
  for( i=1;i<=NF;i=i+1 ){ 
    if ($i ~ /[aeiou]/ ){
      c=c+1; 
    }
  };
  if(c==20){
    print $0
  }
}
```

And this is what it does ... it only prints back the one string that has 20 vowels.

```
echo "contributorNickSequestionsfoundcontainingvowelsgrcep" |  awk -f nicks.awk
echo "contributorNickSeoquestionsfoundcontainingvowelsgrcep" |  awk -f nicks.awk 
contributorNickSeoquestionsfoundcontainingvowelsgrcep
echo "contributorNickSaeoquestionsfoundcontainingvowelsgrcep" |  awk -f nicks.awk
```

Comment: Nice! that's cool, unfortunately this is a homework question that only allows grep or egrep expressions to find this answer

Comment: If you're learning regular expressions. Try [https://www.regular-expressions.info/](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) for some excellent resources.

Answer (score 0):

If all you really need is to find 20 vowels in a line then that's just:

```
awk '{x=tolower($0)} gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&",x)==20' file
```

or with grep:

```
grep -Ei '^[^aeiou]*([aeiou][^aeiou]*){20}$' file
```

To find words (assuming each is space separated) there's many options including this with GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='\\s+' -v IGNORECASE=1 'gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&")==20' file
```

or this with any awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {x=tolower($i); if (gsub(/[aeiou]/,"&",x)==20) print $i} }' file
```